# Struts 2 Form Bind Parameters To Collection Without Using Index

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2, ognl

Struts Version: 2.3.16.3

Is there a way to populate a list of objects without having to specify the index?  Currently I have to reference the collection like so:

```xml
<input name="myCollection[0].myProperty" value="some value" />
```

I really want to be able to do something like this:

```xml
<input name="myCollection[].myProperty" value="some value" />
```

I am dynamically adding and removing elements on the page with JavaScript and it has been a pain to get the indexing right with the JavaScript.  Rather just have the backend add to the end of the collection in the order the elements come across from the form.  Similar to how PHP processes it.

The docs for the [parameters interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) say that it is really just a ognl expression that the input name is binding to.  I went to the [ognl docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) and it says you can reference array's like this:

```xml
array["length"]
```

which would be the next element in the array.  The parameter interceptor is spitting out a message that it is rejecting this parameter name.  I would really like to find a way to make this happen, even if it means extending the parameters interceptor.

Comment: *`array["length"]` which would be the next element in the array* - this isn't correct. Create String list variable in your action class and reference it like so `name="list"` in jsp.

Comment: Why not to specify the index in the collection bound to the parameter name?

Comment: @AleksandrM It is a collection of objects, or am I not understanding what you are saying?

Comment: Do you have more object properties beside `myProperty` that you need to add dynamically?

Comment: @RomanC It becomes a pain when dealing with pages that are dynamically removing elements off the page.  I am usually doing this with tabular data and the user can add/delete rows off of the table.  When they delete the row, you end up with a gap in the index which generates a null at that position in the collection.  It either needs to be addressed with JavaScript, remove nulls from the List in the controller, or put a if null continue in the controller when processing the list.  It seems like there should be a easier solution by modifying the parameters interceptor if it cannot handle this.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes it is a complex object with more than 1 property.  I was just trying to simplify the example.

Comment: You cannot simple remove indexes, because it is the only way to determine which object some property belongs to.

Comment: @AleksandrM yup you're right, I do not know why I was not thinking of it that way.  It would have no idea when to jump to the next index.  You would have to send some other special param to tell it to go to the next index.  Yours is the direct answer to my question.  If you want to post it as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @PaulZepernick Dealing with indexes is a nightmare, but OGNL supports 3 kind of indexes not especially  the same like ones used in Java or JavaScript collections. May be you update which index are you using.

Comment: @RomanC: *OGNL supports 3 kind of indexes* - Which ones? Some link?

Comment: @AleksandrM Can you please post the link to the new question here if it has been asked?

Comment: @PaulZepernick: There is no such thing as kinds of indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need somehow to identify which object some property belongs to. Indexes are simplest way to do that, so you cannot just remove them.

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Look at Andrea's answer for one possible solution using javascript.

You can also pull object properties to simple lists and later set them to object.

E.g.

```
private List<String> myProperty;
```

can be referenced in JSP w/o indexes:

```
<input name="myProperty" value="first value" />
<input name="myProperty" value="second value" />
```

Of course you if you have many properties you need to somehow *sync* them in JSP in such way that order and size of the properties in list is consistent for every property.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since

1. you are manipulating the page with Javascript
2. you are having troubles detecting / updating the index of elements when adding / removing them

the simplest solution is:

1. use the syntax you prefer when manipulating them, for example `myCollection[].myProperty`, and
2. convert them into the form desired by Struts **in a pre-submit function**.

This way you don't have to bother with the indexes while manipulating the elements, but only once, at the end, when you can simply loop them by name or something, and change their name with javascript by assigning the right index.

A kick-off example with jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
    $('[name^="myCollection[]"]').each(function(index) {
      var oldV = this.name;
      var newV = oldV.replace("myCollection[]", "myCollection[" + index + "]");
      console.log("was: " + oldV + " - now is: " + newV);
      this.name = newV;
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  Open Javascript Console, then press submit, then inspect input elements
  <br>
  <input name="myCollection[].myProperty" />
  <br>
  <input name="myCollection[].myProperty" />
  <br>
  <input name="myCollection[].myProperty" />
  <br>
  <input name="myCollection[].myProperty" />
  <br>
  <input name="myCollection[].myProperty" />
  <br>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done something similar before.  Looking to avoid the index all together.

Comment: it would be one less thing to worry about if it's possible

Comment: This is a valid solution for anyone looking how to add the index, but it was not the info I was looking for.  I am already managing the index, I was looking for a way to avoid the index all together.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you find a way to do it, remember to come back and answer your own question... good luck :)